# Panda Datetimes: get datetime ranges from lists of datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-3.6

Not sure if relevant, but the dates are in DatetimeIndex list(?) in Panda, Python 3.6

I'm trying to get all the date ranges of consecutive days, outputting the minimum and maximum of the said date ranges.

Output preferred to be in list, but it seems like Dataframe is essentially a list where I can use indexing, I think?
I would later output these date ranges to an Excel sheet.

Sample input:

```
'1990-10-01', '1990-10-02', '1990-10-03', '1990-10-05', '2002-10-05', '2002-10-06'
```

Expected output:

```
1990-10-01, 1990-10-03  
1990-10-05   
2002-10-05, 2002-10-06
```

I know a naive method would be to do a for loop and check if the next/previous dates is off by one, checking the day, month, and year. But what's a better way to do this?

Thanks

Edited to clarify

Comment: why is `'1990-10-01', '1990-10-02'` not in the expected output ?

Comment: @YOLO The OP wants the earliest date and latest date for each consencutive group

Comment: do you want the output as list or dataframe?

Comment: @YOLO Sorry, I have edited the post.

Comment: @U10-Forward is correct.

Comment: @anky_91 edited the post, probably list, but I just need it so I can output those date ranges to an Excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Lets create the example:

**Input:**

```
l = ['1990-10-01', '1990-10-02', '1990-10-03', '1990-10-05', '2002-10-05', '2002-10-06']
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(l)
```

---

```
DatetimeIndex(['1990-10-01', '1990-10-02', '1990-10-03', '1990-10-05',
           '2002-10-05', '2002-10-06'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

---

**Solution:**

Create a helper series which will calculate the [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) between the consecutive dates and create groups where difference is not 1 , then loop over the groups and get the first and last item in that group.

```
g = idx.to_series().diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=1)).dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()

final = [pd.DatetimeIndex(map(grp.index.__getitem__, (0,-1))) 
                         if len(grp.index)>1 else grp.index
                         for _,grp in g.groupby(g)]
```

---

**Output:**

```
[DatetimeIndex(['1990-10-01', '1990-10-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),
 DatetimeIndex(['1990-10-05'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),
 DatetimeIndex(['2002-10-05', '2002-10-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)]
```

If you want a dataframe to do `df.to_excel(..)` , just create a dataframe based on the `final` list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(final,columns = ['start','end'])
print(df)

       start        end
0 1990-10-01 1990-10-03
1 1990-10-05        NaT
2 2002-10-05 2002-10-06
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(['1990-10-01', '1990-10-02', '1990-10-03', '1990-10-05', '2002-10-05', '2002-10-06'])
```

**Solution:**

First calculate running diff, create a flag to indicate if the dates should be in the same group, then groupby and get the start and end date for that group. Set is used to remove end date if it's the same as start.

```
(
    df.assign(DateDiff=(df.Date - df.Date.shift(1)).dt.days.fillna(0))
    .assign(Flag= lambda x: np.where(x.DateDiff==1, np.nan, range(len(x))))
    .assign(Flag=lambda x: x.Flag.ffill())
    .groupby(by='Flag').Date
    .apply(lambda x: set([x.iloc[0].date(), x.iloc[-1].date()]))
)

Flag
0.0    {1990-10-01, 1990-10-03}
3.0                {1990-10-05}
4.0    {2002-10-05, 2002-10-06}
Name: Date, dtype: object
```